# Trilogy: Planet with tech banned and space weapons stopping landing and leaving the native population have talons

Tags: story-identification, books

The books started in space with a admiral being betrayed and stranded with a few staff making friends with the mongol-type population that have talons, not nails, and try to take over the world.

Comment: all tec band = all technology is banned?

Comment: Please consider writing in complete separate sentences, and with some overall attention to using easily readable writing form. It isn't difficult, there is no rush, and it's kind to the people you're asking to help you.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read the book and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).